# GNU Make: Canned recipe which is meant to generate prerequisites for rule causes error "No rule to make target"

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, gnu-make

I have this simple Makefile:

```
define some_canned_recipe
find 'foobar' -print
endef

run-something: $(call some_canned_recipe)
    @$(info ** [Make] run-something)
    @touch $@
```

I want the 'run-something' rule to be run if and only if one or more files or directories has changed under subdirectory 'foobar'. When I invoke 'make run-something' inside WSL2 however I get this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'find', needed by 'run-something'.  Stop.
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want (in terms of dynamically generating the prerequisites for the 'run-something' rule)?

PS: I'm aware that a silly solution would be:

```
define some_canned_recipe
$(shell find 'foobar' -print)
endef
```

even though this works its not really a good idea because $(shell ...) will run even when the rule 'run-something' is not being targeted.

Comment: First: The prerequisite list is _always_ evaluated (in the first pass of `make`) so what you say about the `$(shell )` call is true for every other function also. Secondly, you need to specify more clearly, what you mean by "directories have changed". With files there is only one interpretation in the context of `make` (modification date), but for directories this is less clear. BTW you seem to have understood the difference between `shell` and `make` syntax, why do you call the second a silly solution - the first one is the wrong one.

Comment: "directories have changed"=any file-related change in them (incl. create/delete file). I explained why I consider using $(shell ...) a bit silly: a hefty makefile with many rules each of which has its own list of dynamic dependencies is bound to cause 'make' to load slowly due to it needing to scan multiple directories for all rules instead of just for the rules needed to perform the desired operation. I was expecting 'make' to be a bit smarter/optimal in this regard. But it is what it is. Feel free to make an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: You can put all directories and files with a `$(wildcard _glob-expression_)` into a `make` list. This serves the same purpose as your `find` but is executed from within `make` and therefore hopefully faster. The _glob-expression_ is the same as you would use when `ls`ing for these elements. If you face an unknown number of subdirectory levels, a function like `wildcard-rec` at https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt is needed.

Comment: Note that (1) `make` *will* evaluate function calls when it parses the makefile, before formulating a build plan, and (2) even if you were ok with that, it seems questionable that the resulting rule would have the semantics you really want.  With respect to the latter, as long as the rule is phony, it will not (directly) notice updates to files for which the makefile has no build recipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) combined with implicit rules:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
run-something:

run-%: $$(shell find 'foobar' -print)
        @$(info ** [Make] $@)
        @touch $@
```

(note the `$$` before the `shell` function)

I make no comments on whether I think this is the best way to do it :).

Comment: But this doesn't alleviate the described problem: the evaluation of all necessary prerequisite lists is just delayed, not executed ad-hoc like the user wanted

Comment: Oh right, I forgot: it's still executed for explicit rules.  You'd have to use an implicit rule to actually get it to not execute.